# How do I add JS HTML files to a @Template in Angular 2 (Like $templateCache)?

Tags: angular

This is probably poorly worded, but in my existing Angular 1 projects I use a bunch of HTML resources that are precompiled into a JS file using HTML2JS. This works great so now I am considering my approach for Angular 2. Since HTML2JS has not been updated, everything seems to revolve around 2 strategies.

First you add the HTML inline inside the @tempate atScript. This caches it so I am not going to the server all of the time, but it also makes it difficult to format in IDEs and reduces readability IMHO.

The second is to use an external file and use the url inside of @template. This seems to make things more readable but limits the amount of caching. This means that I need to make larger server calls which I would like to avoid.

Is there a way to have a file start out in HTML then be compiled into a .js file and included in an Angular2 component?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using gulp to compile, you can use the angular-embed-templates plugin. Here I am loading the templateUrl into the template, before compiling to javascript in the dist folder, with source maps:

```
var gulp           = require('gulp');
var ts             = require('gulp-typescript');
var sourcemaps     = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var embedTemplates = require('gulp-angular-embed-templates');

gulp.task('ts:build', function () {
    gulp.src('app/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(embedTemplates())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(ts({
            noImplicitAny: true,
            module: 'system',
            target: 'ES5',
            experimentalDecorators: true,
            moduleResolution: 'node',
            emitDecoratorMetadata: true
        }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

Comment: Looks promising.  Works with angular2?

Comment: yep using it with angular2, now I'm just trying to write a plugin to do the same thing with the styleUrl.

Comment: So what type of files does this support? Jade? Also is this saying the templates would still be in ES5 and just ported over?

Like why does it say the extension is ts?

Comment: Ts is for typescript files but this would support any extension. The plug in was made for angular 1 and .js

Comment: Completed the sass plugin for the same thing:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular2-embed-sass

Comment: This is unexpectedly seamless solution.

Comment: Just taking down the check because of the Gulp issues listed and it seems more inline with the direction of the ng2 team. Still a great answer though! I will add it back if people think that is a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

Since Webpack is the new Gulp ([also Gulp needs some help](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1604)), [here is what I came up with (uses stylus and jade)](https://github.com/jrgleason/ng2-webpack-demo)...

Use Webpack loaders like this...

```
loaders: [
  {
    include: /\.pug/,
    loader: 'pug-html-loader'
  },
  {
    test: /\.styl$/,
    loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!stylus-loader'
  },
  {
    test: /\.ts$/,
    loader: 'ts'
  }
]
```

Then use requires in your components like this...

```
@Component({
    ...
    template: String(require('./navbar.component.pug')),
    styles: [String(require('./navbar.component.styl'))],
    ...
})
```

**Make sure to use `styles` and `template` instead of `templateUrl` and `styleUrls`**